# set the month based on the route for the calendar month component

Tags: angular, primeng-calendar

I have create a calendar component where I would like to select the default month or based on the route parameters that are getting for the component

Here is the calendar

```
<p-calendar [maxDate]="dateTime" [(ngModel)]="selectedMonth" name="selectedMonth" dateFormat="MM" view="month" [yearNavigator]="true"
    [monthNavigator]="true" (onSelect)="updateDaysInMonth($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

In my component I am calling like this

```
<app-calendar class="p-element mr-2"></app-calendar>
```

Here is the stackblitz for the same https://stackblitz.com/edit/uvubg7?file=src%2Findex.html.

I will get the month in queryparams where I will read as follows

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const month = params['month'];
      const year = params['year'];

      if (month) {
        this.showTimesheets(month, year);
      }
    });
```

I would like to show that month(example January/February) by default upon routing the component

Comment: The code looks fine but the question is unclear. What is the current problem ? Where does it fail ?

Comment: Hi @ArnaudDenoyelle let us say when I am loading the page by default I am able to set the Month to current date. But I have a scenario where I will pass the data as query string like 1 or 2 in that case I would like to set the selected date to January/February based on the param

Comment: I have just updated the fiddle to navigate to timesheet component from another. If you see default it was to February but in query string as parameters I am passing 1 so it should select January

Comment: It depends if we are talking about the month number (january = 1) or the month index (january = 0). This depends on the library you are using but you probably just have to set -1 to the month in that case. It seems that you are relying on the native `Date` implementation so, in that case, it is a month index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I am able to figure it out when the component was called the parent component is called initially and then child was loaded. So I did this way

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectedMonth = new Date(params['year'], params['month'] - 1, 1);
    });
  }
```